# how to get a jTable focused that is inside a jWindow?

Tags: java, jtable, visible, jwindow

Here's my code...

```
private void cdescKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { 
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == 40 | evt.getKeyCode() == 38) {
                jWindow2.requestFocusInWindow();
                selectitemstable.requestFocusInWindow();
                selectitemstable.requestFocus(true);
    }
```

}

What I wanna do is that when I press Up or down arrow keys, I want jWindow2 that has the jTable inside to be visible and to focus to the jTable so I can navigate it using the keyboard? my jTable is inside the Other Components and jWindow1 is an object that I created manually. My JFrame has a Free Design layout....

Comment: try using requestFocus(); without the true or false inside the parenthesis.

Comment: already did, but it is not working... :(

Comment: Maybe you have the key-codes wrong : (VK_KP_UP) is for the up arrow key. In fact, here is the full list (: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Comment: actually I checked that too, I used  System.out.println(evt.getKeyCode()); to check them and those are the correct keycodes..

Comment: so let me get this straight. You're working with two separate JFrames? Window1 is the main frame, Window2 is a separate one created manually that has the JTable. You want a key listener that, when you press arrow-up in Window1, to open Window2 with the JTable focused on and visible?